# React-Redux: mapStateToProps with async call

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, reselect

I'm very new to react and redux and i'm having a problem.

**NOTE**: i need the flow described later because my application have a dynamic menu that is "handled" on the server.

In my application after `Login` screen i display a `Dashboard` component that load data (in async way):

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.loadAllSystems();
    }
    ...
```

The render method of Dashboard is very simple:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <LeftNavigation className={style['left-navigation']} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Now, `LeftNavigation` component have the state connected with react-redux:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        systemsTypes: getSystemsTypes(state)
    }
};
```

The property `systemTypes` is null until `this.props.loadAllSystems();` finish loading and fire an action to update the state.

The `getSystemsTypes` is written with `reselect`:

```
export const getSystems = state => state.systems.collection;

export const getSystemsTypes = createSelector(getSystems, (systems) => {
    if (systems.length > 0) {
        return Object.keys(systems[0].monitors);
    }
});
```

As you see, to fix this I have added a check on systems.length to avoid errors on Object.keys.

In this way the application works but, this is correct or i'm doing something wrong ?

I didn't used `redux-thunk`, i'm using `redux-saga` but I guess this is not a problem.

Comment: To fix what? You didn't say what the problem was?

Comment: To fix "errors" i've introduced systems.length >0 because the selector is called when the component is created and the async call can not be completed yet...

Comment: That's not an error, that's completely normal. You have two states: first it's `null` so `length` is `undefined`, then your next state contains the data.

Comment: So, is correct what i have implemented ? the question is just this :) Or, i've do in a wrong way an there is another solution. If it is ok, i say you thanks :)

Comment: it seems like all is ok